# Getting error while posting login info on ASP.NET WEB API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am getting this exception while trying to do a post call on a ASP.NET Web API. I am calling this from a Windows Universal App:

> Type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType0`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]'
>   cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the
>   DataContractAttribute attribute.

Here is my code:

```
    var loginData = new { grant_type = "password", username = name, password = pass };
    var queryString = "grant_type = password, username = " + name + ", password = " + pass;

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        string resourceAddress = "http://localhost:24721/Token";
        //int age = Convert.ToInt32(this.Agetxt.Text);
        //if (age > 120 || age < 0)
        //{
        //    throw new Exception("Age must be between 0 and 120");
        //}

        string postBody = Serialize(loginData);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage wcfResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress, 
            new StringContent(queryString, Encoding.UTF8));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. i updated the post data as key value pair and it worked.

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string resourceAddress = "http://localhost:24721/Token";
            var requestParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", name),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", pass)
            };
            var requestParamsFormUrlEncoded = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestParams);
            var tokenServiceResponse = await client.PostAsync(resourceAddress, requestParamsFormUrlEncoded);
            var responseString = await tokenServiceResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var responseCode = tokenServiceResponse.StatusCode;
            var responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(responseCode)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(responseString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
            return responseMsg;
        }
```

Comment: You can also try to manually serialize youir data before sending to API

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is, you're getting that error because the serializer you're using doesn't support anonymous types. I would recommend trying to use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), which handles them nicely. I believe you can include it from NuGet.

If you reference the library in your project then you could modify your code like so:

```cs
var loginData = new { grant_type = "password", username = name, password = pass };

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
try
{
    string resourceAddress = "http://localhost:24721/Token";

    string postBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectloginData);
    var content = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage wcfResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress, content);
}
```